# Filter which should send questions daily now sending once a week!

Tags: bug, tag-filters

I have a [filter](https://stackexchange.com/users/2142012/jim-cownie?tab=subscriptions) which shows as being daily, yet recently I have only been getting updates weekly. What gives? I didn't change anything!